# Diabling Symfony2 sessions files

Tags: php, session, symfony

I'm looking for a way to disable the file saving of PHP sessions. (I do not need sessions in my application)

I tried to set `save_path = NULL`, but it only set it to the default path (/tmp).

Is there a way to do that ? Or maybe I shouldn't do it at all for reasons I ignore ?

Comment: If your application doesn't actually use sessions, where are they coming from?

Comment: I guess it's Symfony2, or one of the bundles that creates them by default. I am going to take a look, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I disabled the saving of session in Symfony2 directly, by adding `stateless` to the `app/config/security.yml` file :

```
firewalls:
    api:
        stateless: true
        pattern: ^/
        http_basic:
            realm: "Authentification needed"
```

This way the sessions are used but not stored in files.

Answer (score 1):

PHP should only be creating session files is session_start() is called in your application (meaning it needs them) or PHP is configured to always start sessions.

Make sure `session.auto_start = 0` is set in your php.ini so that the sessions are not started automatically

Once that's set if you aren't creating sessions then your save path shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: If you _really_ wanted to disable sessions you could also create a current `session_set_save_handler()` which called empty functions, hence doing nothing.